# Is there a Perl module to convert c99 hex floating point notation to regular notation?

Tags: perl, floating-point, hex, string-parsing

Is there a built-in library that I can use to convert c99 style floating point notation, example: 0x1.0p23f, to regular floating point numbers using Perl (and vice versa)?

Comment: Related: stackoverflow.com/questions/770342

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing built-in, but CPAN is your friend. The [Data::Float](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Float) module has `hex_float` and `float_hex` functions to do this.